# PM2 restart with application id is not working

Tags: node.js, pm2

I've a node js project, In this project I'm using `Typesript`. So, I'm trying with pm2 start with below command

```
tsc && NODE_ENV=development pm2 start ./build/server.js --name project-dev
```

and result of the above is below

[image]

and my `ecosystem.json` file is

```
{
    "apps": [{
        "name": "group",
        "script": "ts-node",
        "args": ["server.ts"],
        "cwd": "./",
        "watch": true,
        "env": {
            "NODE_ENV": "development"
        },
        "env_testing": {
            "NODE_ENV": "testing"
        },
        "env_staging": {
            "NODE_ENV": "staging"
        }
    }]
}
```

here my question is

1. `pm2 reload 0` is not taking the new changes
2. Even though in ecosystem has watching is enable but why its not affecting ?
3. How do I solve this ?

Comment: As far as you are running tsc before starting script with pm2 you are facing this behavior, you can create some script in package.json like `"start": "tsc && node ./build/server.js"` and then execute `pm2 start npm --name "project-dev" -- start`. However, not the best use case for production to make your tool for orchestration handle the build process.

Comment: I tried to configure in `package.json` still I'm facing same issue @DenisMalykhin

Comment: well, have you tried the exact command that I've shared?

Comment: Yes I tried but there is a downtime when I'm restarting with `pm2 restart <id>`

Comment: hm, that's the difference between restart and reload. Reload is the one without downtime. So the reason is simple, you should include your tsc invocation inside the start script. Otherwise, you're running tsc ones, before the pm2 start. That's why the file changes aren't applied.

Comment: I tried with pm2 reload <id> still there is downtime

Comment: how to do tsc invocation invocation ? how to solve this issue

Comment: How many instances do you run, in your example is only one, so there will be downtime. You should have at least 2 for 0-downtime

Comment: In that case I can stop the app id and start it again, yes I've only one instance - I want to reflect all my changes without downtime

Comment: Yup, I've just tested the solution, that I've posted above it works. Exactly as you asked.

Comment: You cannot achieve 0-downtime with one instance. The Idea behind reload is that it works with several instances. It will reload each instance in time. To make sure that other alive. You can read more about what is that here https://dzone.com/articles/zero-downtime-deployment

Comment: I tried with your command but i have a downtime with `pm2 reload <id>`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230291/discussion-between-denis-malykhin-and-change-need).

Comment: @changeneed it's not using the settings in the json because you're not telling pm2 to use them, try `pm2 start ecosystem.json`

Comment: u still have this problem???